# Filtering tags in M2M Field Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So I have my models

```
Class Category((models.Model)
    category = models.CharField()

class Group(models.Model)
    Title = models.CharField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name= tags)
```

So I want to be able to filter all the groups with similar tags to the group currently in view

In my views.py I tried

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=pk)
groups = Group.objects.filter(category=group.category)
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: What are "similar" tags? One tag in common? All tags of `group` should be in the categories of the `groups`, exact match (these and *only* these categories)? Something else?

Comment: Okay, so every group has the opportunity to select already existing tags, but they are not limited to one tag, so let's say Group A has the following tags Movie, Anime and Music, and Group be has only Music I want to be able to retrieve group be since it has a similar tag with group A

Comment: on category has  one or more groups  and  one group   has one or more categories , m2m field  in the database level is  a separate table   check the docs  for clarification https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the groups that have *at least* one `Category` in common with:

```
Group.objects.filter(category__in=group.category.all()).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) prevents listing a `Group` that many times as there are matching `category`s.

Another option is to use the relation in reverse, and thus work with:

```
Group.objects.filter(category__tags=group).distinct()
```

The related name however does not make much sense: the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) is the name of the relation in reverse, `related_name='groups'` thus makes more sense. In that case we query with:

```
Group.objects.filter(category__groups=group).distinct()
```